# My database become read-only when I am using Inno

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created an Access Database and want to be able to install it with inno.

When I am using the default database format it works properly, but when I am using the ACCDE format it make it read-only type.

How can I avoid Read-only type?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid Read-only type.

You can't; and you shouldn't, as the purpose of the *accde* format is to make the file's code and objects read-only.